# jQuery href navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple page.  I only want to show one division at a time and navigate in the body using href #'s.  I think I need to show / hide based on an anchor link being clicked.  Thank you.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="home">
        <a href="#" rel="test">Go To Testing Number</a>
    </div>

    <div id="test">
        <a href="#" rel="home">Home</a>
        <p>Testing Number</p>
        <input type="number" value="0" />
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').not('#home').hide();   // show home page first
});

// this function needs to change I think, it does not work properly
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $(target).hide();
   $("#"+target).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//this should work fine 
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var     target = $(this).attr('rel');
    If(target == "home"){
        $("#home" ).hide();
        $("#test").show();
    }else{
        $("#test" ).hide();
        $("#home").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: this will work on a very limited role; I want easy, powerful code; thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're showing the selected DIV correctly, but your code for hiding the other DIVs is wrong. Why did you think `$(target)` would select the DIV that's already showing?

Give all the DIVs for different tabs the same class so you can hide them all in one call.

```
<div id="test" class="tab">
    <a href="#" rel="home">Home</a>
    <p>Testing Number</p>
    <input type="number" value="0" />
</div>
```

Then the jQuery would be:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(".tab").hide();
    $("#" + target).show();
});
```

Comment: that does not work for me, can you do a JFiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after hours of research online.  Simple and powerful.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').not('#home').hide();   // show home first

    $('a').click(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div').not(target).hide();
        $('div').filter(target).show();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xinthose/d715adtk/4/)